# Directly read analog voltage using PWM duty cycle timer registers

Tags: pwm, arduino-leonardo, analogwrite

I'm outputting an analog voltage by setting an 8-bit duty cycle using `analogWrite`. Once set, I'd like a way to read back this duty cycle. I've managed to read the duty cycle back from the `OCR4D` register, which matches the value set, e.g.:

```
pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
analogWrite(6, 123);
Serial.print(OCR4D);   // 123
```

However, when setting the duty cycle to `0` or `255`, `OCR4D` is not actually set at all; instead `analogWrite` calls `digitalWrite` behind the scenes and the pin is digitally set to `LOW` or `HIGH`. This is seen in the source for `analogWrite`:

```
if (val == 0)
{
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
}
else if (val == 255)
{
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
}
else
{
// set PWM duty cycle as normal...
```

The problem with this is that `OCR4D` is simply left at its previous value, so it's not always possible to tell the actual output by reading `OCR4D` alone. In other words there is no way to tell the difference between:
- PWM is active and `OCR4D` reflects the duty cycle
- PWM is disabled and `OCR4D` reflects a previous duty cycle (which is not useful)

Which register(s) can I read to crosscheck the PWM is active?

I'm also aware of the `pulseIn` function, but would rather read the PWM register directly.

Comment: `digitalRead(pin)` will tell you if it's 0 or 1

Comment: Unfortunately it also turns off PWM for that pin: `if (timer != NOT_ON_TIMER) turnOffPWM(timer);`. I want to read the value without changing it @dandavis.

Comment: i thought you said that PWM was already turned off for those values? you would only use the digitalRead if the other failed.

Comment: Ah, sorry @dandavis my question wasn't very clear, I've since updated it. PWM does get disabled for those values, but it's not possible to tell if `OCR4D` is "wrong" as it always returns a valid duty cycle (it just keeps the old value). What I'm after is a way to tell if the PWM is active and that value is being applied.

Comment: ahh. the way i do this in my projects is to define `analogWrite2(pin, val)`, which sets an external array of values by the pin number, then calls the real `analogWrite()` with the passed values. You can refer to the array from anywhere for a fast reliable read. Just run a replaceAll w/ `analogWrite2`...

Comment: Thanks @dandavis I wanted to avoid caching, but that's also a nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I managed to do this by reading the timer/counter control register relevant to pin 6:

```
// read the voltage on an analog output pin
int analogReadOutput(int pin) {
    switch(digitalPinToTimer(pin)) {
        case TIMER4D:
            if (TCCR4C & (1 << COM4D1)) {   // PWM active
                return OCR4D;
            } else {                        // PWM not active
                return 255 * digitalRead(pin);
            }
        case TIMER4A:
            if (TCCR4A & (1 << COM4A1)) {   // PWM active
                return OCR4A;
            } else {                        // PWM not active
                return 255 * digitalRead(pin);
            }
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes two things that possibly aren't always true (outside of my simple program):

- `COM4D1` bit is a reliable way of telling if PWM is enabled,
- duty cycle value is 8 bit with a max of 255.

Comment: arduino turns on/off the COMx bits for pwm controls -> take a look at turnOffPWM(). So a more reliable way is to read those bits to determine if a pin in in pwm or digital mode. actually a simple modification of turnOffPWM() would be more consistent in my view.

Comment: Yes @dannyf that's certainly more reliable. In my case the relevant bit is `COM4D1`. Edited answer to match.

Comment: If your own answer works please accept it.